# Carrinho com opcionais dinamicos com Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema: como subtrair 2 arrays com angularjs.

Já tentei de varias maneiras e não consegui fazer essa subtração.

Estou criando um carrinho de produtos com opcional dinâmico em angularjs

nesse caso o cliente fez a seguinte modificação:

incremento o id 1004, 1000 decremento o id 1001 adicionou o id 1002

receita original:

```
[{"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":1},{"id":1000,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1},{"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":3}]
```

receita modificada:

```
[{"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":2},{"id":1000,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":2},{"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":1},{"id":1002,"idproduto":2,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1}]
```

Estou precisando que reformule esse array pois preciso mostrar as alterações no carrinho de compras para o cliente.

Produto 500

+1 1004 (R$1,00)

+1 1000 (R$2,00)

+1 1002 (R$2,00)

-2 1001 (R$4,00)

Receita final para o carrinho

```
[{"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":1},{"id":1000,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1},{"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":-2},{"id":1002,"idproduto":2,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1}]
```

E no final teria que somar o array original com o final para dar baixa no estoque.

Estou correto nessa logica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome desta operação é diff, e você quer obter o delta (diferença) entre as duas coleções.

Existe uma *library* chamada [jsondiffpatch (link)](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) que pode ser útil pra você. A saída é o delta (diferença) entre duas fontes.

O exemplo acima resulta no seguinte delta de acordo com esta *library*:

```
{
  "2": {
    "quantidade": [
      3,
      -2
    ]
  },
  "3": [
    {
      "id": 1002,
      "idproduto": 2,
      "forma": "Bacon",
      "preco": 2,
      "quantidade": 1
    }
  ],
  "_t": "a"
}
```

Comment: blz vou testar, mas de qualquer forma brigado!

Comment: pow meio que nao funcionou do jeito que imaginava... teste com o demo e foi o mesmo exemplo seu... fico faltando muitos dados... o jeito certo nao seria o array da receita final nao?

Comment: @Willian o objetivo da operação é expor a diferença; você pode combinar o resultado com seu array original da maneira como desejar.

Comment: então consegui implementar agora me da uma dica ai como fazer virar um array = o da receita final

Comment: pow @OnoSendai tava pensando sobre esse assunto axo que nos array[2] precisava de uma referencia pra saber de qual item se trata a modificação... o como puxaria o resto dos itens que são adicional igual o bacon?